# facebook js sdk notification callback response changes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

Just a quick question to make sure i'm on track - 
I've started supporting a ready FB app. 
Yesterday the client reported an issue with a part of the app which uses the fb JS SDK notification plugin.
In the callback the code refers to (this is only the callback of the entire FB.io):

```
}, function(res) {
                if(typeof(res)!='undefined' && res != null){ // if user invited friends
                        var ids = res.request_ids.toString();
```

but when I console.log the res object, there is no res.request_ids - onlt res.request and res.to (which contains the IDs).

Can it be that Facebook changed the response object? I could find the official docs which say that i'm correct about the object - there are 'request' and 'to' properties, no request_ids -  but why would it work till now? was there a change in the response object? is there a place where these changes are published in advance in order to prevent downtime?
Thanks...

Comment: OK, found it:
here : 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ under:Updated Request ID Format
It says that it can be changed back by changing the setting in the app advanced settings, called Request 2.0 Efficient switched to off. the only problem is that there is no such setting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Can it be that Facebook changed the response object?*"

Yes, they announced the change February of last year. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/

"*I could fin"d the official docs which say that i'm correct about the object - there are 'request' and 'to' properties, no request_ids - but why would it work till now?*"

Official documents:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests

"*Was there a change in the response object?*"

Yes, see: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/

"*is there a place where these changes are published in advance in order to prevent downtime? Thanks...*"

Yes, you will want to read their developers blog at: http://developers.facebook.com/blog

Comment: Thanks for the answer... (I found the source you mention - commented my post) but its good to know where to know in advance about those things. Thanks for the time and knowledge :)